# jsPDF fromHTML() not show image

Tags: javascript, jspdf

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="customers" >
   <div class="">
  <div class="heading">
      <img class="form_head" src="http://dev.syntrio.in/kchr-project/images/kchr-kchr.png" alt="">
</div>
<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">PDF</button>
```

JS CODE:

```
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = $('#customers')[0];

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 10000
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

I am included jspdf.debug.js. When I click the pdf button, pdf was generated, but the image in the html code is not displayed. I got a blank pdf. Please help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but my image is not seen because i tried it in chrome , firefox tried it on and if it worked , indicating that the code is fine. I clarify that I do not know much this topic , but if you want to operate in any browser you can use a web server.

Comment: I got a solution for this. But I don’t know is its correct way. I am converting the image to base64 encode then it works

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

I am Changed my above html code to :

```
<div id="customers" >
   <div class="">
  <div class="heading">
      <img class="form_head" src="base64encoded data of the  image" alt="">
</div>
<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">PDF</button>
```

Then its works for me

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/anjuarya/xzZ7n/3643/embedded/result/)

Comment: This worked for me as well. Just to clarify, convert the image to base64 then set it (the base64 string of the image's data) as src of the image. It's very frustrating there's this one image from Api that refuses to show in the pdf